# Is this graph planar?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I know almost nothing when it comes to graph theory.

I have this graph which i am told is not planar.

I know that for planar graphs no edge can cross another edge
and that for planar graphs $v - e + r = 1$ where $v = |V|$ is the number of vertices, e = |E| is the number of edges and $r$ is the number of minimal enclosed regions.

My graph meets these criteria.

To show that it is not planar, if that is the case, should i try to find a graph that it is isomorphic to which is not planar?

Any ideas on how to do that?

This is my graph with an improved version on the right:

[image]

Comment: "planar" means you can draw it in the plane with no edge-crossings. If that picture is your graph, it's planar – you have drawn it in the plane with no edge-crossings.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, that confused me. I was almost sure it was planar but was told it was not. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @JKnecht, Can you draw this graph with little bit clear how many vertices and edges, please?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Its a little bit clearer now i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the above graph is planar, because it admits a plane drawing. A plane drawing is a drawing without edge-crossings much like yours above, and finding such a drawing is already a valid proof of planarity.

To show that some other graph is not planar, you could first check if it perhaps has too many edges (i.e. more than $3n-6$ if the graph has $n$ vertices) or, if this fails, you could look for a *subdivision* or a *minor* isomorphic to one of the graphs $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. Both latter statements are characteristic of non-planarity and hence the methods always work (at least in principle). You can look up details and definitions by googling Kuratowski's theorem.

Also, I'd be careful saying that $r$ is the number of minimally enclosed regions as this number would not quite be well-defined if the graph were drawn on the surface of a sphere (which is a perfectly fine equivalent definition of planarity) - it is safer to think of the infinite region as an extra region of the graph, in which case the polyhedral formula for connected planar graphs modifies to $v-e+r=2$.

Answer (score 0):

As the definition of planar graph states that " a planar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane, i.e.,it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other."

> Your given graph is already drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other.

---

**Alternative way :** For a simple, connected, planar graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges, the following simple conditions hold:

Theorem $1.$ If $v ≥ 3$ then $e ≤ 3v − 6$;

Theorem $2.$ If $v ≥ 3$ and there are no cycles of length $3$, then $e ≤ 2v − 4$.

Given, graph has $e=13$ and $v=9$, therefore:

$\implies e ≤ 3v − 6$

$\implies 13 ≤ 3\times 9 − 6$

$\implies 13 ≤ 21$ is true, so graph is planar.

Note that these theorems provide necessary conditions for planarity that are not sufficient conditions, and therefore can only be used to prove a graph is not planar, not that it is planar.

---

**Another way:** Euler's formula states that if a finite, connected, planar graph is drawn in the plane without any edge intersections, and $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ is the number of edges and $f$ is the number of faces (regions bounded by edges, including the outer, infinitely large region), then

$\implies f=e-n+(k+1)$

where $k$ is number of connected component.(for given graph $f=6$, five bounded region and one unbounded region and $k=1$, since connected graph).

Therefore,

$\implies 6=13-9+(1+1)$

$\implies 6=6$ is true, so graph is planar.

Comment: NO! $e\le3v-6$ and $e\le2v-4$ do NOT guarantee that a graph is planar! Take a graph that violates those conditions, add on a lot of new vertices without adding on too many new edges, and, voila! you have a nonplanar graph that satisfies the inequalities. Or, just take the Petersen graph, q.v.

Comment: The thing about Russia is probably that Russia comes in two pieces, one of which borders on Lithuania and Poland. But I'm not sure whether that makes the graph nonplanar.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are correct. I've edited answer.

Comment: Also, Euler's formula *assumes* the graph is planar, so it can't be used to *prove* a graph is planar. Indeed, you can't even define "face" if the graph isn't already known to be planar.